# Error in the virtual function table while extending inet c++ class

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to extend some inet modules in my own project. If I use the code below, I get a segmentation fault error. The debugger shows for example that Radio.cc wants to call medium->addRadio(this); and in fact it calls SCTPOpenCommand::setLocalAddresses(const AddressVector& localAddresses), which is absolutely not used in the project.

MyRadioMedium.ned

```
package test.physicallayer.common;

import inet.physicallayer.apskradio.packetlevel.APSKScalarRadioMedium;

module MyRadioMedium extends APSKScalarRadioMedium
{
    parameters:
        @class(MyRadioMedium);
}
```

MyRadioMedium.h

```cc
#ifndef INET_MYRADIOMEDIUM_H_
#define INET_MYRADIOMEDIUM_H_

#include "inet/physicallayer/contract/packetlevel/IRadioMedium.h"
#include "inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/RadioMedium.h"

namespace inet {

namespace physicallayer {

class INET_API MyRadioMedium: public RadioMedium {

public:
    MyRadioMedium() : RadioMedium() {}
protected:
    virtual bool isInCommunicationRange(const ITransmission *transmission, const Coord startPosition, const Coord endPosition) const override;
};

} // namespace physicallayer

} // namespace inet

#endif
```

MyRadioMedium.cc

```cc
#include <MyRadioMedium.h>

namespace inet {

namespace physicallayer {

Define_Module(MyRadioMedium);

bool MyRadioMedium::isInCommunicationRange(const ITransmission *transmission, const Coord startPosition, const Coord endPosition) const {
    // some code
    return true;
}

} // namespace physicallayer

} // namespace inet
```

Screenshots showing gdb on windows and ubuntu

- [working, gdb + ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqgBc.png)
- [not working, gdb + windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHjh.png)

Comment: Could it be that some other part of your code overwrote your vtable? Running your simulation with a memory access checker (e.g., valgrind's memcheck) might shed some light on this in either case.

Comment: the error only exists with omnet++ and windows. I used valgrind with omnet++ and ubuntu and the simulation runs without problems

Comment: This is weird. Does a gdb stack backtrace look sane?

Comment: I posted two screenshots showing gdb on windows and ubuntu. It don't look sane on windows.